# python - get difference between two times

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I have a simple question today. I want to get the difference between the 2 dates and check if the difference is around ~5 minutes.

And I found a problem with getting the difference, to check.

I compared the same date with one that had a few minutes difference, and it printed a difference of -1 day? That doesn't make sense to me.

Test it yourself, if you want.

Compared Dates:

```
Date1: 2021-05-15 00:38:57.244000
Date2: 2021-05-15 02:40:42.245693
```

The printed difference was:

```
Diff: -1 day, 21:58:14.998307
```

So why is it at -1 day? Shouldn't the difference be just ~2 hours? And what's the best way to get the difference between the 2 dates? **As I said, I want to check if the difference is smaller (or equal to) 5 minutes.** How is that possible if the dates can be every time different?

**Important info:** The dates are always different because I check account creation dates.

I used this code to make the difference:

```
diff = date1 - date2
```

Comment: what if you do `date2 - date1`?

Comment: The dates are always different because i check account creation dates.

Comment: date2 is later than date1, so `date1 - date2` is negative.  Don't you want `date2 - date1` instead?

Comment: @JohnGordon Because I compare account creation dates, the date1 or date2 can be every time different. It can be a date from 2018 or 2021, and date2 too. I just want a method to check if the difference between the both dates is smaller (or equal to) 5 minutes.

Comment: Compare the dates to see which is smaller, then subtract accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved by ordering the two date objects so that the diff comparison always returns a positive number. Then you can use a timedelta object to check if the diff is less than 5 minutes.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Define dates as datetime objects
Date1 = datetime.fromisoformat("2021-05-15 00:38:57.244000")
Date2 = datetime.fromisoformat("2021-05-15 02:40:42.245693")

# Define 5 minutes as a timedelta object
five_minute_duration = timedelta(minutes=5)
```

Compare the two dates by subtracting the older date from the newer date. The result will be a timedelta object.

```py
diff = Date2 - Date1
```

If you're not sure which date object is the older and younger, you could sort them. This will make the comparison stable and prevent the unexpected negative timedelta.

```py
dates_sorted = sorted([Date2, Date1])
diff = dates_sorted[1] - dates_sorted[0]
```

Difference in hours. In this the example, the duration is 2.029... hours.

```py
diff.total_seconds() / (60 * 60)
```

Check if the diff is smaller or equal to the 5 minute duration.

```py
if diff <= five_minute_duration:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do compare operation before minus operation. Example is as shown below.

```
from datetime import datetime

dt1 = datetime(2020, 4, 19, 12, 20)
dt2 = datetime(2020, 4, 21, 15, 2)

def get_date_diff(date1, date2):
    diff = date2 - date1 if date1 < date2 else date1 - date2
    return diff

def test():
    print (get_date_diff(dt1, dt2))

test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an upper and lower bound by creating two timedeltas with positive and negative values for the allowed difference

```
lower = timedelta(minutes=-5)
upper = timedelta(minutes=5)
```

Then check if the difference between the datetimes falls within those bounds

```
lower < date1 - date2 < upper
```

The advantage to this approach is that if this comparison is made many times `lower` and `upper` can be created just once and no sorting of the datetimes has to be performed